# error due to single quote in a parameter in url query string

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a screen from which I am passing a parameter to other screeen. This parameter contains a single quote. (For eg. ABC's xyz). The other screen shows this paramter correctly on screen. However, I am not able to submit the request on load to servlet. I am not able to figure out why?
Tried using URL encoding, replacing ' with \' and replacing ' with %27. Didn't work for me. Plz help.

The code is as follows.

```
child page var scheme = document.forms[0].scheme.value;
                window.location.href = redirectVal+".jsp?levelOfReport="
            + levelOfReport
            + "&circleCode="
            + circleCode
            + "&networkCode="
            + networkCode
            + "&moduleCode="
            + moduleCode
            + "&regionCode="
            + regionCode
            + "&branchCode="
            + branchCode
            + "&circleName="
            + circleName
            + "&moduleName="
            + moduleName
            + "&branchName="
            + branchName
            + "&Amount="
            + Amount
            + "&scheme="
            + scheme + "&fromDate=" + fromDate + "&toDate=" + toDate;
```

Child page

```
            SubmitButton('./Report.do?method=getAgriProductWisePerformanceReport&levelOfReport=&scheme=<%=request.getParameter("scheme")%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the end to your method call.

`SubmitButton('./Report.do?method=getAgriProductWisePerformanceReport&levelOfReport=&scheme=<%=request.getParameter("scheme")%>`

Map your quotes to eachother, you're telling it to do something like

`SubmitButton('./SubmitButton('./Report.do?method=getAgriProductWisePerformanceReport&levelOfReport=&scheme=HTTP`

You need to add an additional `');` at the end of that line